# Number theory / induction

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have problem with this questions

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive integer numbers which defined by :

$a_1=5$ , $a_2= 13$ , $a_{n+2} = 5 a_{n+1} - 6 a_n$

for all $n\ge 1$

prove that $a_n= 2^n + 3^n$ ?

I start

i) for n=1

L.H.S: $a_1=5$ , R.H.S: 2^1 + 3^1 =5  , so R.H.S = L.H.S

ii) assume that for n=k

$a_k$ = 2^k + 3^k

iii) must  prove that's true for n= k+1

L.H.S:  $a_{k+3}$ =$5 a_{k+2}$ - $6a_{k+1}$

I have problem , how do i complete this ?

Comment: You could try induction

Comment: i tried but i couldn't

Comment: Edit your effort and tell us where got stuck.

Comment: What have you tried?  Standard methods work fine here...

Answer (score 1):

To make this induction proof work, you need to verify the first *two* bases cases, not just the first *one*. That is, you need to check that

$$2^1+3^1=2+3=5=a_1$$
and
$$2^2+3^2=4+9=13=a_2$$

(For example, if the problem had stipulated $a_2=12$ instead of $13$, the sequence would be $5,12,30,78,\ldots$, which does not satisfy $a_n=2^n+3^n$.). The induction hypothesis is not just $a_k=2^k+3^k$ but also $a_{k+1}=2^{k+1}+3^{k+1}$, and the key step is

$$\begin{align}
a_{k+2}&=5a_{k+1}-6a_k\\
&=5(2^{k+1}+3^{k+1})-6(2^k+3^k)\\
&=5(2\cdot2^k+3\cdot3^k)-6(2^k+3^k)\\
&=(10-6)2^k+(15-6)3^k\\
&=4\cdot2^k+9\cdot3^k\\
&=2^{k+2}+3^{k+2}
\end{align}$$

In other words, the logical statement "$P(k)$" you need to prove by induction is not just $a_k=2^k+3^k$ but rather

$$(a_k=2^k+3^k)\land(a_{k+1}=2^{k+1}+3^{k+1})$$

where "$\land$" is the logical *"and"* symbol. The key step above shows that

$$(a_k=2^k+3^k)\land(a_{k+1}=2^{k+1}+3^{k+1})\implies (a_{k+2}=2^{k+2}+3^{k+2})$$

while it's obvious that

$$(a_k=2^k+3^k)\land(a_{k+1}=2^{k+1}+3^{k+1})\implies(a_{k+1}=2^{k+1}+3^{k+1})$$

(i.e., $p\land q\implies q$, which is always true). Thus

$$(a_k=2^k+3^k)\land(a_{k+1}=2^{k+1}+3^{k+1})\implies(a_{k+1}=2^{k+1}+3^{k+1})\land(a_{k+2}=2^{k+2}+3^{k+2})$$

or $P(k)\implies P(k+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$n=1$: $5 = a_1 = 2^1+3^1$ and $n=2$: $13 = a_2 = 2^2+3^2$.

For the induction step, let $n\geq 1$. Then by definition and induction hypothesis,
$a_{n+2} = 5a_{n+1} - 6a_n = 5(2^{n+1} + 3^{n+1}) - 6(2^n+3^n) = 5\cdot 2^{n+1} + 5\cdot 3^{n+1} - 3\cdot 2^{n+1} - 2\cdot 3^{n+1} = (5-3)2^{n+1} + (5-2)3^{n+1} = 2^{n+2} + 3^{n+2}.$ Done.

Comment: thanks a lot ^^ , how i missed that

Answer (score 0):

I would wsrite $$b_n=2^n+3^n$$ and show that $$a_n=b_n$$ for all $n$
Base case: $$b_1=a_1=5$$
let $$b_k=2^k+3^k$$
$$b_{k+1}=2^{k+1}+3^{k+1}$$ so $$a_{k+2}=5(2^{k+1}+3^{k+1})-6(2^k+3^k)$$
Can you finish?

Comment: I see , that's why i couldn't answer , thank you so much